# Flutter Drawer: Is it possible to scroll only part of the drawer?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, drawer

I'm trying to build an app where you could open a drawer and scroll only content below DrawerHeader(). When I have DrawerHeader as a child of ListView, naturally it scrolls with the whole list. I've tried 
`Drawer(child:Column(children: <Widget>[DrawerHeader(), ListView()]))` 
but seems that it crashes the app.

[test drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4miA.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Projects related tools'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
            ExpansionTile(
              title: Text('Project 1'),
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Property 1'),
                Text('Property 2'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(child: ListView()),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your ListView with an Expanded:

```
Drawer(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        ...
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          ...
      ),
    ),
  ],
 ),
),
```