# Flutter - Drawer with Expanded and ListView scroll not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make the question simple. I need to make a `Drawer`, It gives me below error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

I want the drawer to have 3 sections:

```
|--------------------------------|
|                                |
|           DrawerHeader         |
|                                |
|--------------------------------|
|--------------------------------|
|                                |
|         Scrollable Area        |
|                                |
|           ListItem1            |
|           ListItem2            |
|           ListItem3            |
|                                |
|                                |
|--------------------------------|
|--------------------------------|
|                                |
|        Copyright Section       |
|                                |
|--------------------------------|
```

```
Drawer(
  child : Column(
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(
          padding: const ..,
          child: ....,
        ),//DrawerHeader
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: const [
              ListTile(
                leading: ...,
                title: ...,
              ),//ListTile
              ExpansionTile(
                title: ...,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    leading: ...,
                    title: ...,
                  ),//ListTile
                  ListTile(
                    leading: ...,
                    title: ...,
                  ),//ListTile
                  ...
                ], //<Widget>
              ),//ExpansionTile
              
              Divider(thickness: 1),
              
            ],//children
          ),//ListView
        ),//Expanded
        const SizedBox(height: kSpacing * 2),
        const Text("Copyright. All Rights Reserved"),
        const SizedBox(height: kSpacing),
      ],//children
    ),//Column
);//Drawer
```

I've tried more that 8 solution that came up from 4 days searching. here are some examples

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720170/4719854):

Error

> Failed assertion: line 2817 pos 12: '!_needsLayout'

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718208/4719854):

Error

> Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803961/4719854):

Error

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

And tried removing `Expanded`, use `SingleChildScrollView` but still doesn't work for me

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide child instead of `....,` that will reproduce the issue

Comment: And everything is working fine from provided snippet structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a SizedBox of specific height to give bound for the column that will define a bound for the expanded widget too

```dart
Drawer(
  child : SizedBox(//<---here
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
   child : Column(
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(
          padding: const ..,
          child: ....,
        ),//DrawerHeader
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: const [
              ListTile(
                leading: ...,
                title: ...,
              ),//ListTile
              ExpansionTile(
                title: ...,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    leading: ...,
                    title: ...,
                  ),//ListTile
                  ListTile(
                    leading: ...,
                    title: ...,
                  ),//ListTile
                  ...
                ], //<Widget>
              ),//ExpansionTile
              
              Divider(thickness: 1),
              
            ],//children
          ),//ListView
        ),//Expanded
        const SizedBox(height: kSpacing * 2),
        const Text("Copyright. All Rights Reserved"),
        const SizedBox(height: kSpacing),
      ],//children
    ),//Column
  ),//SizedBox
);//Drawer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working well https://prnt.sc/JX49BJc8dyvL

```
Drawer(
    child : Column(
      children: [
        DrawerHeader(
          child: Container(color: Colors.black),
        ),//DrawerHeader
        Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    title: Text('Red')),
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "items.playerName",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "items.description",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Divider(thickness: 1),
              ],)),
        const SizedBox(height: 10 * 2),
        const Text("Copyright. All Rights Reserved"),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],//children
    ),//Column
  ),
```

Comment: I've tried this but gave me `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of search and trying different structures.
Probably you are using desktop flutter as me.

[this Link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93862) offers a simple solution when it comes to error

> scrollcontroller attached to multiple scroll views

when you use the structre `Drawer -> Expanded -> ListView -> ExpansionTile`

**Explaination:**

It happens because of how `ScrollView`s treat default (null) primary on them. It defaults to true if direction is vertical and there is no scroll controller. Because of that, all your vertical scroll views' scrollbars attach to the `PrimaryScrollController`, and that is why this error occurs

**Solution:**

mark appropriate `ScrollView`s with `primary: false`, so that you are left with no more than one primary `ScrollView`